# How to change data of all unique ids inside a child?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The parent is Messages and inside that i have a Senders Id and inside that is Receivers Id and inside that are unique ids.

Inside unique Ids there are 2 childs - from and seen. I want to change all the seen values to true whose from value equals "a particulate value"

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you concider using triger?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, iterate through all your nodes and then just change the values of all the Seen inside RecieversID

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("Messages").child(sendersID).child(RecieversID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DatasnapShot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               snapshot.child("Seen").setValue(true);

            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
          }
        });
```

Comment: what about the condition